# How do I clear this error stating that Invalid click event

Tags: vue.js

Editorial.vue;

```
    <templates>
      <div class="col offset-2">
           <router-link to="editorial">
              <base-button type="info" @click="saveUserData">Save</base-button>
           </router-link>
       </div>
    </templates>     


   data() {
        return {
        userdetails: {
        logoURL: null
               }
            }
           },

   methods: {
                   
      saveUserData: function () {
         let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('logoURL', this.userdetails.logoURL)
     this.api.uploadFile('editorial/'+store.state.journalId+'/editorialimage'
       ,formData'journals/v1/').then((res) => {
        this.userdetails.journalId = store.state.journalId
        this.userdetails.imageId = res.data.status
        this.createNewMember()
         }, (err) => {
       console.log(err)
         })
          },








    When I click save button I'm getting the below error

    "Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

    found in

   ---> <BaseButton> at src/components/BaseButton.vue
    <RouterLink>
      <Card> at src/components/Cards/Card.vue
       <Anonymous>
         <ZoomCenterTransition>
           <DashboardLayout> at src/pages/Layout/DashboardLayout.vue
             <App> at src/App.vue
               <Root>"

    "I'm getting the above error I don't the solution, the function name also mentioned correctly but still I'm getting the same error. Searched some of the solution but nothing worked. The function posting some data to the server but while clicking the button getting the error". Tried lots of ways to solve this but its all failed.
```

"I'm getting the above error I don't the solution, the function name also mentioned correctly but still I'm getting the same error. Searched some of the solution but nothing worked. The function posting some data to the server but while clicking the button getting the error". Tried lots of ways to solve this but its all failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that `base-button`? if that a custom component, you need to define `emit` event from the component, so the parent can catch the event and fire the `saveUserData` function

you might be want to provide some information about your custom component

here some detail how to use `emit`
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Comment: <component
    :is="tag"
    :type="tag === 'button' ? nativeType : ''"
    :disabled="disabled || loading"
    @click="handleClick"
    class="btn"
  >
    <slot name="loading">
      <i v-if="loading" class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </slot>
    <slot></slot>
  </component>
methods: {
    handleClick(evt) {
      this.$emit('click', evt);
    }
  }